# Get value from back end to front end

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a post method on the backend ( Spring boot )  that returns the `id` when I post data.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fncs", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public int addFnc(@RequestBody Fnc fnc){
        fncservice.addFnc(fnc);
        return fnc.getN_fnc();
    }
```

I want to create a function in angular service that return me the `id` (number) ,I tried it with this function but it didn't work.

```
const baseUrl = 'http://192.168.100.9:8081/fncs';



 create(data): Observable<any>  {
       
      return this.http.post(baseUrl, data);
    }
```

I carried out the work of the function
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in your case. However it is not considered best practice to return directly an integer from a Rest Api. You should consider to wrapp it  inside a JSON object.

```
   create(data): any  {
           
        this.http.post(baseUrl, data, { responseType: 'text'})
         .subscribe((res) => {
         //response will be parsed as text and we need to convert it to int
         const resInt = + res;   
         console.log(resInt);         
         return resInt;
         }, 
        (error) => {
        console.log(error);
          }
       )
   }
```

I doubt you need it as it is here. However you can check that this will work in your case of seeing the response. Actually you need to use the subscribe method not here on the service but wherever you want to do something with the response.

Comment: there is a lot of errors in your code , you define the function to return observable and you return resInt( who is type int and not defined )

Comment: yea thanks. I have not compiled it and have written it quickly just to point out how this thing will work. Now I have corrected it.

Comment: there is a prblm in error : error No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(error: any) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.ts(2769)
Observable.d.ts(54, 5): The last overload is declared here.

Comment: Still the same prblm : Argument of type '(error: any) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<string>) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.ts(2345

Comment: Try again with updated answer. This should erase all errors. However you need to attach this subscribe function not here but wherever you want to call this service. And then this subscribe function must not return a value but instead put the returned value into another value of your component. So if your component calls this service it must do it like service.create().subscribe((res) => { console.log(res); this.componentData = res; }); So subscribe does not return anything it just put the value into another variable that is going to stay inside the component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226410/discussion-between-hamza-nouri-and-panagiotis-bougioukos).

Answer (score 1):

```
You could just add the ".subscribe" method to receive the data after finishing the post request and dealing with the coming output like this:

    create(data): any{    
        this.http.post(baseUrl, data).subscribe({
        next: data=>{
           return data
        },
        error: error => {
        return 0
}
})
        
    }
```

Comment: So now when I call create methode from service she will return number for me ?

Comment: @HamzaNouri Logic wise, It should yes if you return the value after the setting. I can't implement it at the moment myself so do it and check.

Comment: data.id where is the id the all method in back end return number   I  don"t send a variable  called id

Comment: you could log the data you get back and then decide what you want to return after that.

Comment: base url + data returns for me a number, I only want to modify the create function so that it returns this number. I don't think it's so complicated at this point. I don't use angular for that I couldn't do it.

Comment: he asks to declare the variable id he can't find it , check the function in back end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226408/discussion-between-hamza-nouri-and-moataz).